Error when tracing llm calls with Langsmith (Failed to get info from https://eu.smith.langchain.com) (Failed to batch ingest runs: LangSmithError))
I have an issue with lansgmith setup. I tried to search on the web for this issue, but could not find a solution. I follow these steps:

Created a new fresh environment:

conda create --name test_langsmith python=3.11
conda activate test_langsmith
pip install -U langchain langchain-openai
pip install python-dotenv

Created and .env file with the following content:

LANGCHAIN_TRACING_V2="true"
LANGCHAIN_ENDPOINT="https://eu.smith.langchain.com/"
LANGCHAIN_API_KEY="my_lansmith_key"
LANGCHAIN_PROJECT="Test_project"

OPENAI_API_KEY="my_openai_key"


Created a "main.py" script with the following content:

from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv(".env")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    llm = ChatOpenAI()
    llm.invoke("Hello, world!")



When I run the script, I get the following error:

Failed to get info from https://eu.smith.langchain.com: JSONDecodeError('Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)')
Failed to batch ingest runs: LangSmithError("Failed to POST https://eu.smith.langchain.com/runs/batch in LangSmith API. HTTPError('405 Client Error: Method Not Allowed for url: https://eu.smith.langchain.com/runs/batch', '<html>\\r\\n<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>\\r\\n<body>\\r\\n<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>\\r\\n<hr><center>nginx</center>\\r\\n</body>\\r\\n</html>\\r\\n')")
Failed to batch ingest runs: LangSmithError("Failed to POST https://eu.smith.langchain.com/runs/batch in LangSmith API. HTTPError('405 Client Error: Method Not Allowed for url: https://eu.smith.langchain.com/runs/batch', '<html>\\r\\n<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>\\r\\n<body>\\r\\n<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>\\r\\n<hr><center>nginx</center>\\r\\n</body>\\r\\n</html>\\r\\n')")

Can someone help me? What am I doing wrong?

The correct LANGCHAIN_ENDPOINT environment variable is "https://eu.api.smith.langchain.com" and not "https://eu.smith.langchain.com".
